# How do I extract elements of a column in a series or a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a column of objects in a dataframe that comes out looking like this when I inspect it in my notebook via `tappers_df['TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE']`

[Jupiter notebook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HhhG.png)

The dataframe's index is made up of the 'Corp' strings you can see in the image. The 'TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE' column in [[double brackets]] are dates followed by amounts. Each different 'Corp' index item appears in the list anywhere from 2 to 16 times and has anywhere from 1 to 15 date/amount pairs in the 'TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE' column. So for 'Corp' index items that appear twice, those rows of the column look like this:

- AF125751 Corp [[2015-07-17, 5150.0]]
- AF125751 Corp [[2015-07-17, 5150.0]]

For 'Corp' index items that appear three times, the rows look like this:

- AL997424 Corp [[2017-06-01, 1632000.0], [2017-12-07, 1065000]]
- AL997424 Corp [[2017-06-01, 1632000.0], [2017-12-07, 1065000]]
- AL997424 Corp [[2017-06-01, 1632000.0], [2017-12-07, 1065000]]

And so on. For the first instances of each 'Corp' index item, I am grabbing the dates and and amounts I need from other columns in the dataframe. For the subsequent ones, I'm trying split this column up into its component parts, such that the result will look like this *(Note: I'm using '|' here only as a visual demarcation between the two columns)*

- AF125751 Corp [1st date] | [1st amount] *(again, taken from other columns)*
- AF125751 Corp 2015-07-17 | 5150.0 *(ie, the 1st and only TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE date/amount pair)*
- AL997424 Corp [1st date] | [1st amount] *(again, taken from other columns)*
- AL997424 Corp 2017-06-01 | 1632000.0 *(ie, the 1st of 2 TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE date/amount pairs)*
- AL997424 Corp 2017-12-07 | 1065000 *(ie, the 2nd of 2 TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE date/amount pairs)*

I'm a beginner, so please be specific in your suggestions. I have tried every iteration of `extract`, `iloc`,`loc`, `np.where` and other thing I can think of. Thanks much or your help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is your question?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple columns unwantedly combined, because you read in a whitespace-separated CSV without specifying `pd.read_csv(..., sep='\s+')`. Please go back and show us the commands you used to import the data. You wouldn't need to extract individual columns if you hadn't combined them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for question. The data is being downloaded via an API from the Bloomberg terminal, so I have no choice about how it comes in. For each item, the API downloads a table of two columns and as many rows as required. When imported into a dataframe, this is how it looks. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Could this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd
df_dict = {'index': ['AF125751 Corp', 'AL997424 Corp', 'AL997424 Corp'], 
           'TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE': [[['2015-07-17', 5150.0]], [['2017-06-01', 1632000.0], ['2017-12-07', 1065000]], 
                                   [['2017-06-01', 1632000.0], ['2017-12-07', 1065000]]]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict).set_index('index')
s = df.apply(lambda d: pd.Series(d['TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df_split = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE'])
pd.DataFrame(df_split['TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE'].values.tolist(), columns=['DATE', 'VALUE'], index=df_split.index)
```

The code creates a Series out of each nested list (each Series row is a [date, value] pair), stacks those Series, then resets the MultiIndex created in the stacking process. This results in a Series object. Next, it recreates a DataFrame object similar to the one you had at the start.

By the way, you could also remove duplicate rows before doing all that by running:

```
df[~df.index.duplicated()]['TAP_REOPEN_SCHEDULE']
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Will try this in a bit. By the way, I actually need the duplicates, because each will have a separate date, based on the TAP REOPEN SCHEDULE.